# Swift String to unsigned char [](CUnsignedChar)

Tags: ios, c, swift

Hello i'm trying to use an old legacy C library that uses buffers (unsigned char []) to transform the data. The main issue here is that I couldn't find a way to transform a String to a CUnsignedChar and then be able to alloc that buffer to a UnsafeMutablePointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert a Swift string to an immutable C string to pass to a C function, try this:

```
let s: String = "hello, world!"
s.nulTerminatedUTF8.withUnsafeBufferPointer { p -> Void in
    puts(UnsafePointer<Int8>(p.baseAddress))
    Void()
}
```

You may need to use `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` if your function takes an `unsigned char *`.

Answer (score 0):

I turn String to NSData first ,then turn NSData to CUnsignedChar array

```
if let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){
        var rawData = [CUnsignedChar](count: data.length,repeatedValue: 0)
        data.getBytes(&rawData, length: data.length)

}
```